# Jquery match an attribute including the value

Tags: jquery, html, css, search, attr

I have a page of displaying simply links everything from images to .ppt files. Looking at the code below, how can I target specific attribute i.e. fileext=".ppt" and append a class to the link depending on the extension?  I am using ASP.NET MVC, and jQuery

```
<a class="screenshot" title="" fileext=".ppt" rel="http://google.com/test.jpg" href="#">
```

Comment: Just FYI, URLs go in the `href` attribute, not the `rel` attribute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('a[fileext=".ppt"]').addClass('foo');
```

For more information:

- [jQuery Attribute Equals Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)
- [jQuery .addClass() function](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

You can do this for each file type separately, but if you have a lot of them, then you'll probably want to take the value of the `fileext` attribute and automatically match it to a class name. If you could give some more examples of the links you have and the classes you want to apply to them, that would be helpful.